# The navigationItem on NavigationBar is shifted when scrolling on tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uinavigationitem

[image]

When I scroll on tableView, the navigationItem is not hide and move a little to bottom.
i tried it on lower version (iOS 13, iOS 12), however this issue is happen on iPhone 11 (iOS 14).
I searched any resource to find out solution for it, but it still not help me.
So what should i do now ?

```
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.playerDefaultColor
        UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white

        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.premiumFontActiveColor
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put an empty view above your tablview if `UITableView` is the first view in your view hierarchy. If that fixes it, you can leave that view in xib and make it hidden. It sounds weird but I had same issue in previous versions of xcode which was fixed by this solution.